# Changing the value of a column based off of another column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, and whenever the classification column is 1, I want to add the string "black" to it.
This is what my dataframe is right now:

```
   Explanation                              Classification:
 blue, red, pink                                   1
  green, red                                       0
 yellow, purple                                    0
      red                                          1
```

and this is what I want:

```
   Explanation                              Classification:
 blue, red, pink, black                            1
  green, red                                       0
 yellow, purple                                    0
      red, black                                   1
```

please help!

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```py
df.loc[df.Classification == 1, "Explanation"] += ", black"
```

NB: Depending on your application, it might be a good idea to split the color column into separate columns for each color (e.g. if you ever need to count colors).

Comment: I don't know why that didn't work :/

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Maybe share some sample data (see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/15873043)). Are the column names correct?

Comment: I didn't realize that 1 in my dataframe was cast as a str instead of an int like it was in this example. it works now, thank you!